# orbeon autocomplete get selected item

Tags: autocomplete, orbeon, xforms

I'm using the fr:autocomplete control for autocompletion of street names. The control itemset is filled by the returned address objects (streetname+number+zip+city) from an http service. I read in the documentation that you can bind only with a single-node value. So only the streetname can be bind to the street node.

The problem is i need to bind over values of the selected address with other nodes, such as number, zip and city, at the same time.

Can you show me please how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a high level idea.

You can have a temporary node and have the binding to autocomplete control.

You can write xforms:action on event `DOMActivate` and have setvalue commands all your address fields.

When user selects an address detail, Assuming address detail is space seperated (Eg: StreetXYZ 123 556277 Tokyo), this value is assigned to temporary node.

In the setvalue commands you can use xpath functions `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` to fetch each component.

I will try to give an example later. All the best!

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer but i have to precise that my address object is composed of multiple fields like street name, numper, zip code and city. Its not a whole address string. And when an address is selected, i have to bind only the street name to the autocomplete control, and the other values to other input fields.

Comment: <Street>
<name/>
<municipality>
<zipCode/>
<municipalityCode/>
<name/>
</municipality>
<pwmc/>
</Street>